# ChartJS ignores 'chartOptions'

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I can't find out how to set the "chartOptions", neither with the help of the documentation (https://vue-chartjs.org/), nor other tools.

For this I built a simple sandbox environment on codesandbox.io, so you can have a closer look.

There you can find two bar charts in the folder "components". Both have a different approach and both ignore e.g. the "min" and "max" value when scaling the chart. Just like the chart title is ignored, too. In the meantime I don't know what I can or should do. In the meantime I have tried everything possible and I just can't find a solution.

I need to define the options externally, or at least be able to override them before rendering. The second option would be even much better!

I would be very happy if someone could help me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-3-chartjs-zz5194?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: It does not work because your prop is called `chartOption` instead of `chartOptions`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that really took me many hours and I just did not see it :-(